# How worthwhile is this optimization for Heapsort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heapsort, max-heap

The traditional `Heapsort` algorithm swaps the last element of the heap with the root of the current heap after every `heapification`, then continues the process again. However, I noticed that it is kind of unnecessary.

After a `heapification` of a sub-array, while the node contains the highest value (if it's a `max-heap`), the next 2 elements in the array *must* follow the root in the sorted array, either in the same order as they are now, or exchanging them if they are reverse-sorted. So instead of just swapping the root with the last element, won't it be better to swap the first 3 elements (including the node and after the if necessary exchange of the 2nd and 3rd elements) with the last 3 elements, so that 2 subsequent `heapifications` (for the 2nd and 3rd elements ) are dispensed with?

Is there any disadvantage with this method (apart from the if-needed swapping of the 2nd and 3rd elements, which should be trivial)? If not, if it is indeed better, how much performance boost will it give? Here is the pseudo-code:

```
function heapify(a,i) {
  #assumes node i has two nodes, both heaps. However node i itself might not be a heap, i.e one of its children may be greater than its value.
  #if so, find the greater of its two children, then swp the parent with that value.
  #this might render that child as no longer a heap, so recurse
 }

function create_heap(a) {
   #all elements following index |_n/2_| are leaf nodes, thus heapify() should be applied to all elements within index 1 to |_n/2_|
   }

function heapsort(a) {
  create_heap(a);  #a is now a max-heap
  #root of the heap, that is a[1] is the maximum, so swap it with a[n].
  #The root now contains an element smaller than its children, both of which are themselves heaps.
  #so apply heapify(a,1). Note: heap length is now n-1, as a[n] is the largest element already found
  #now again the array is a heap. The highest value is in a[1]. Swap it with a[n-1].
  #continue
  }
```

Suppose the array is `[4,1,3,2,16,9,10,14,8,7]`. After running a `heapify`, it will become `[16,14,10,8,7,9,3,2,4]`. Now the `heapsort`'s first iteration will swap 16 and 4, leading to `[4,14,10,8,7,9,3,2,16]`. Since this has now rendered the root of the new heap `[4,14,10,8,7,9,3,2]` as, umm, un-heaped, (14 and 10 both being greater than 4), run another `heapify` to produce `[14,8,10,4,7,9,3,2]`. Now 14 being the root, swap it with 2 to yield `[2,8,10,4,7,9,3,14]`, thus making the array currently `[2,8,10,4,7,9,3,14,16]`. Again we find that 2 is un-heaped, so again doing a `heapify` makes the heap as `[10,8,9,4,7,2,3]`. Then 10 is swapped with 3, making the array as `[3,8,9,4,7,2,3,10,14,16]`. My point is that instead of doing the 2nd and 3rd `heapification`s to store 10 and 14 before 16, we can tell from the first `heapification` that because 10 and 14 follow 16, they are the 2nd and 3rd largest elements (or vice-versa). So after a comparison between them (in case they are already sorted, 14 comes before 10), I swap all the there `(16,14,10)` with  `(3,2,4)`, making the array `[3,2,4,8,7,9,16,14,10]`. This reduces us to a similar condition as the one after the further two `heapification`s - `[3,8,9,4,7,2,3,10,14,16]` originally, as compared to `[3,2,4,8,7,9,16,14,10]` now. Both will now need further `heapification`, but the 2nd method has let us arrive at this juncture directly by just a comparison between two elements (14 and 10).

Comment: What kind of `heapification` are you talking about:  bottom-up or top-down?  It seems like your question is referring to some text you have not referenced, so it is difficult to follow your proposal.  Please explain your context, include code or pseudocode, and/or include a link to your text.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your optimization, but how would you ensure the next heapify produces a proper heap if you replace the top three elements instead of just the one?

Comment: Why do you think the next 2 elements in the array _must_ follow the root in the sorted array? Is that guaranteed by the specific heapification algorithm used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second largest element of the heap is present in the second or third position, but the third largest can be present further down, at depth 2. (See the figure in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure) ). Furthermore, after swapping the first three elements with the last three, the heapify method would first heapify the first subtree of the root, followed by the second subtree of the root, followed by the whole tree. Thus the total cost of this operation is close to three times the cost of swapping the top element with the last and calling heapify. So you won't gain anything by doing this.

Comment: Okay, in that case, I will swap the first two with the last two, since the first and the greater of the next two are guaranteed to be the highest and 2nd highest. Will that do?

Comment: The second largest can be present in the third position. So you have to check this, swap the correct elements and call siftDown (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) two times on appropriate elements. That would be correct, but in terms of performance it won't make a difference.

Comment: Why not, normally I would do another `heapification` for the 2nd element also, bt in this case, just at the cost of a possible exchange between the 2nd and 3rd elements, I am doing away with one `heapification`. This will continue every alternate cycle, so won't that save substantial time?

Comment: I don't know what version of heapification you have in mind. In the heapsort algorithm, after we exchange the top element with the last, fixing the resulting heap by calling the siftDown method takes about clogn time since only the top element will have to go the proper position. If two elements close to the root need to be repositioned, then you will have to call sift-down twice on these elements, which will cost you about 2clogn.

Comment: Yeah. In your version, per sifting, you are removing the root node to the last. In my version, I am removing the root node and the greater of its two children nodes to the last. This involves a comparison between the 2nd and 3rd elements to decide which one should accompany the root to the last.